# Sample size problem

Tags: sample-size, sample

I am looking for a suggestions on how to estimate the sample size in such a problem.

There is a group with one usefull treatment (let's say 10 milion people) but one consider if there might be more Effective way of treatment. So a control group is needed (with  adequate size - that's the issue) to Have statistically powierful significance results (if any exist).

The problem is that I don't Have any idea on how to calculate adequate sample size for control group. I'd like to Have the least possible sample size Because of control treatment's High costs.

Thank's for any advice.

Comment: Most sample size calculator allows you to adjust the treatment:control ratio. However, notice that the gain by having more control than treatment diminishes.

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html ; especially: pwr.t.test(n = , d = , sig.level = , power = , type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following link gives some very useful information on calculating sample sizes using R language:

http://statmethods.net/stats/power.html

In your situation, following is likely to be applicable:

```
pwr.t.test(n = , d = , sig.level = , power = , type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired"))
```

You can play with the values to determine the best combination for your study.